# Converting MemberInfo[] to Enum

Tags: c#, reflection, enums

I've been searching for a while but didn't find the solutions. I have an assembly in a GAC. I have to to load it using reflection. After that I need to get and address to Enum. But instead I can just get `MemberInfo[]`. I don't understand how to convert `MemberInfo[]` to `Enum`.

I have code like this:

```
//test assembly contains 
public class MyClass
{
    public enum MyEnum 
    {
        MyVavue, 
        MyValue2
    }
}

Assembly s = Assembly.Load("test");
Type type = s.GetTypes()[1];
MemberInfo[] memberInfos = type.GetMembers(
    BindingFlags.Public | 
    BindingFlags.Static);

//I need to convert memberInfos to MyEnum
//and after that receive ---> MyEnum.MyValue <---
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the memberinfo of a enum in the assembly from the GAC? Or what exactly are you asking because i'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I am trying to get Enum. And address to it  e.g.   MyEnum.One  from GAC I can load assembly.

Comment: A short but complete example or what you're trying to achieve would really help. Are you trying to find a field, a property, something else?

Comment: so something like this: http://geekswithblogs.net/shahed/archive/2006/12/06/100427.aspx ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should simply use `Enum.GetValues`. That's exactly what it does - use reflection to get the enum fields:

```
Assembly s = Assembly.Load("test");
Type type = s.GetTypes()[1];
object[] values = Enum.GetValues(type);
object myValue = values.First(v => v.ToString() == "MyValue");
```

Comment: values gives two results, but they are undefined and I don't have MyEnum type. It exists in the another assembly.

Comment: looks like there is a problem with casting) but thanks for good answer

Comment: +1 - it's a good approach. The limitation of `GetValues` compared to the reflection approach however is that one cannot read custom attributes from the values.

Answer (score 10):

Use `GetFields` instead of `GetMembers` and then call `GetValue(null)` to get the enum value.

Comment: This is the simplest and more accurate answer. Just use `typeof(T).GetFields().Select(a => (T)a.GetValue(null))`

Answer (score 3):

you mayb can use

```
foreach(var member in memberinfos)
{
 Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum),member.Name)
}
```

i havent tried in yet.. but more or less the syntax would be same